# Minimal NSApplication get console input

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation, appkit

**I did setup a minimal application, is there a way how to send console input to it? or how to block it's loop and return control to the console?**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        AppDelegate * delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        NSApplication * application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [application setDelegate:delegate];
        [NSApp run];

        // Get console input
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use any Cocoa features at all?

Comment: Console input? Like using scanf?

Comment: yup, i want to use the runloop nsapp, just to switch control from app to console and back

Comment: I would say that was non-trivial.  For one thing isn't the app disconnected from the controlling tty by virtue of having been created via `launchd`?